# How to grab an distinct attribute using beautifulsoup from an xml file?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, attributes

Here is the data I am trying to extract:

```
<messages>

    <message type="General" code="ER">SECURITY ALERT message(s) found.</message>

    <message type="General">ORDER NUMBER: 7575757</message>

</messages>
```

I am trying just to grab the Order Number: 7575757

I have tried several methods of getting this attribute but with no success.

First attempt:

```
def parseTestID(testid):
    dict = {'ORDER NUMBER': testid.split(" ")[0].split(":")[0]}
    return dict

 


parsedData= []
    
for element in bs_data.find_all("messages"):
    for message in element.find_all("message"):
        dict = {'type': message['type'], 'ORDER NUMBER': parseTestID(message.string)['ORDER NUMBER']}
            # append dictionary to list
        parsedData.append(dict)

    # return list
    print(parsedData)
```

Output:

```
[{'type': 'General', 'ORDER NUMBER': 'SECURITY'}, {'type': 'General', 'ORDER NUMBER': 'ORDER'}]
```

Second attempt:

```
for element in bs_data.find_all("messages"):
    for message in element.find_all("message"):
        print(message.text)
```

Output:

```
    SECURITY ALERT message(s) found.
    ORDER NUMBER: FA3JZ0P
```

I feel that I am close but not quite sure how to grab this specific attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could get that number with the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = '''
<messages>

    <message type="General" code="ER">SECURITY ALERT message(s) found.</message>

    <message type="General">ORDER NUMBER: 7575757</message>

</messages>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
desired_info = soup.find('message', string = re.compile('ORDER NUMBER:')).text.split(':')[1].strip()
print(desired_info)
```

This would return just the number:

```
7575757
```

If you want the full string, then you can skip splitting the string above. BeautifulSoup documentation (which I strongly reccomend perusing, at this point): https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, without `re`:

```py
num = soup.select_one('message:-soup-contains("ORDER NUMBER")').text.split()[-1]
print(num)
```

Prints:

```
7575757
```